# Domain user account showing 'username or password incorrect' on 1 specific PC

Tags: active-directory, domain, windows-server-2016

I have an issue with one domain computer. A user is trying to log in and it says 'username or password incorrect'. I have to go there, and then log in with my credentials, which works. After I log in and log out, he is then able to log in just fine. Then after he goes away and the PC locks, he'll get the same error.
I've reset the PC, rejoined it to the domain and changed his password (even though it wasn't that). It worked for 2 days and then the error came back again.

Is there some debug log I can run on either the DC or his local machine to see what's going on?

Another thing is I don't see his user profile being stores on the bottom left of the logon screen, it's as if his PC isn't saving him. I don't know why having my account log in helps with this.